# Weblogic 12C - Is there a way to edit the variables of a deployment plan from the console?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

We are new to Weblogic (12c). We try to choose how we're going to pass some configurations to the application depending on the environment it is running on (dev / staging /prod).

I'm currently trying to use a deployment plan. In `WEB-INF/web.xml`, I have :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>test</param-name>
    <param-value>11111</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And I use a `plan.xml` for my application in Weblogic. 
Some parts :

```
<variable-definition>
    <variable>
        <name>test</name>
        <value xsi:nil="false">22222</value>
        <description>some description</description>
    </variable>
</variable-definition>
```

and

```
<module-descriptor external="false">
    <root-element>web-app</root-element>
    <uri>WEB-INF/web.xml</uri>
    <variable-assignment>
        <name>test</name>
        <xpath>/web-app/context-param/[param-name="test"]/param-value</xpath>
        <origin>planbased</origin>
        <operation>replace</operation>
    </variable-assignment>
</module-descriptor>
```

This works!

But I heard it could be possible to change the value of the variable *from the administration console*, is that true?

When I browse my application in the console (in the `Deployment Plan` tab or in the `Configuration` tab), I do not see any field which I could use to change the `test` variable... Am I missing something or must the values of overriding variables be set in the `plan.xml` file itself?

Comment: This is a nice and simple example of deployment plan. Way better than the blurry example on docs.oracle.com

Comment: By the way, someone probably misread "by using the Administration Console to update and redeploy an existing deployment plan.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you can change the variable directly, I believe this is because it's a fundamental change to the deploy that requires a "hot update" BUT you can easily "redeploy/update" with a new plan. This is how you would do it in a production environment:

- From the Weblogic admin console, click Deployments, click the checkbox next to your ear/war
- Click Update
- The next screen will ask you for the source path and the deployment plan path, you can change just the deployment plan path to set your new value(s)

You can also call `java weblogic.Deployer` with the `update` option if you want to do it from the [command line](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/wldeployer.html#1008424).

It is also possible to do the same via WLST scripting - see these [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/updateplan.htm)

Comment: I was hoping that maybe there would be a way to change the `plan.xml` file from the console itself (using fields or plain text)), even if an update of the application would be required after! I'll accept your answer if nobody else knows if it's possible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it can be modified from the console itself as well. Right now we use the Update feature for plan.xml changes